# Dividir layout em 2 colunas

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu tenho meu codigo de tela inicial que precisa ser dividida em duas partes iguais.
Como eu divido um *linear layout* em duas colunas com tamanho iguais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar peso:

```
layout_weight= "1"
```

Se os elementos possuir o mesmo peso, terão o mesmo tamanho.

Exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Segue a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

Saudações